# perl regex to find any number that is a multiple of 5

Tags: regex, perl

Perl regex to find any numbers that is multiple of 5.

I tried using `=~ /[5]+/` but it is finding only numbers which contains 5, but not multiple of 5.

And also to find string whose length is multiple of 5.

Comment: You seem to be new at regex, so a little hint: it's only good for strings, you can't "calculate" with regex. There is no `5` in regex, only `"5"` (the string). Are you sure you want to use a regex for that? you could use `if ($number % 5 == 0)` (If my number modulo 5 is equals to 0 => if when I divide my number by 5, nothing is left => if my number is a multiple of 5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer your second question: *And also to find string whose length is multiple of 5.*

That is more suitable for regex than the number part (that has been answered), just group 5 characters and match multiples of them

```
^(?:.{5})*$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?34sf9)

`^` and `$` matches the start and the end of the string.

`.{5}` matches 5 characters (except newlines when you don't use the `s` modifier)

`(?:.{5})*` repeats the inner part of the group 0 or more times ==> this will also match on the empty string! If you don't want this and start only from a string length of at least 5 use the `+` quantifier means 1 or more: `^(?:.{5})+$`

Comment: (That second question wasn't there when the rest of us answered.)

Comment: Why would you use a regex for this instead of `my @filtered_strings = grep { (length($_) % 5) == 0 } @strings`

Answer (score 7):

Numbers that are multiple of 5 either end with 5 or 0.

Try using `/^-?\d*[05]$/`, which means:

- `^` start of string (saflknfvs34535 won't work).
- `-?` A minus sign or not (if you only want positive numbers, don't put that).
- `\d*` numbers, any numbers.
- `[05]` 0 or 5.
- `$` end of string (324655sefgsfgsfg wont' work).

Answer (score 6):

For integers,

```
($_ % 5) == 0
```

or

```
!($_ % 5)
```

Comment: the second one is little faster, i think

Comment: @Suic : Does it even matter?

Comment: @Suic, yeah, it's probably faster in the order of single microseconds (millionths of seconds). I prefer explicitly checking the result of `%` against zero for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Those numbers will end in `0` or `5`, so something like `m/^\d*[05]$/`

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here is a more general solution that works for any divisor:

```
use 5.010;
"150" =~ /^(\d+)(?(?{ $^N % 5 == 0 })|(*FAIL))$/;
```